# Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I have been attempting to add stripe into an app I am trying to get an MVP of at the moment. Whenever I type in the test credit card and click send I get sent to a screen with the following error code.

```
Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

db.collection("users")
  .doc(user?.uid)
  .collection("orders")
  .doc(paymentIntent.id)
  .set({
    basket: basket,
    amount: paymentIntent.amount,
    created: paymentIntent.created,
  });
```

Comment: It seems `paymentIntent` is null

Answer (score 1):

Error here is pretty clear. Looks like your `paymentIntent` is `undefined`.